# Media library player for Chromecast

Tags: sound, google-chrome, chrome-extension, chromecast

How can I play my mp3 library directly to Chromecast Audio?
It would be best to have native application like Banshee or similar to play the files from the disk to Chromecast (I don't want to upload the files anywhere).

The best player I've found so far is: [Cloud flac, mp3, aac Chrome browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cloud-flac-mp3-aac-player/fllklklafhjndfepiellajmaaohlclih). But it allows only select particular files to play, does not allow to select folders. It also has limited features (eg. no browse by artist, album) and ugly interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Chromecast](http://askubuntu.com/questions/324236/how-can-i-use-chromecast)

Answer (score 1):

Currently native Chromecast support on linux is pretty thin. The only client I am aware of is the official Chrome browser extension. It is possible to stream media from a linux machine, but you need to set it up as a file server and control the Chromcast with an android device. There are instructions [here](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/803736-how-to-stream-content-from-a-linux-system-to-chromecast).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have a chromecast audio to test it but pulseaudio-dlna has added chromecast to its devices to be able to do just that.

https://launchpad.net/~qos/+archive/ubuntu/pulseaudio-dlna