# How can I use chromecast with Ubuntu touch (phone)?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, chromecast

Chromecast works just fine with my desktop linux having chromium installed as explained here [How can I use Chromecast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324236/how-can-i-use-chromecast#326224) .

Is it possible to use it with ubuntu touch? My phone is a BQ Aquaris E4.5

Chromium seems not to be in the app store.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, on most of the devices, it's not supported to do so, and there is no way to install and enable the *Cast* extension in the *Ubuntu Browser*.

However, you can set up a *Libertine* container and install *Chromium* in it, with the *Terminal* app or over ssh/adb:

```
$: libertine-container-manager create --id xenial --name 'Chromium'
$: libertine-container-manager install-package -i xenial -p chromium-browser
```

Then, install the *[Desktop Apps Scope](https://uappexplorer.com/app/libertine-scope.ubuntu)* from the store, and it should show *Chromium* to launch. You should then be able to install the *Cast* extension in it. Note though, the E4.5 is very limited in CPU and RAM, and so you may not actually be able to run *Chromium* reliably enough for this purpose on that device.