# How do you use Chromcast with the 32-bit version of Ubuntu?

Tags: chromium, 32-bit, chromecast

With Chromium not having access to the Chromecast extension (or to that just cast ability) and Chrome can't be installed on 32-bit system (I have an Intel processor, can install Windows in 64, but Linux, nah!), how are you suppose to use Chromecast while using the 32-bit version of Linux?

Comment: You should be able to install 64bit linux, why not ? That said, according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/326224/383125), Cromium supports chromecast with the google cast extension.