# How to chromecast from a streaming web page without having it display on the Ubuntu device too?

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

In the Chrome browser, if I'm on a streaming site, a right-click offers me the option of casting to my TV.
The TV has a Google dongle attached and everything works fine, displaying the video both on my Ubuntu screen and on the TV screen.

On YouTube, there is an additional "Cast to TV" icon at the bottom of the screen.
This sends the video to the TV, but without also playing it on the Ubuntu screen.

Playing on both screens is distracting and uses a lot of CPU.

Is there some way of getting this "Cast to TV" effect on other sites that don't offer the "Cast to TV" icon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Chromecast?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324236/how-can-i-use-chromecast)

Comment: If you scroll down, there is an visual answer suggesting the "Cast..." button in the three overflow menu.

Comment: If you want to stop the fact that it "uses a lot of CPU", then you can't without the website support it. Look at the diagram on https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/overview . That button disconnects the video from your browser, and has the Chromecast connect to the website directly.

Comment: @DanielT asks "*Does this answer your question?*".  The top answer there ends with "*Once your device is configured, you should be able to simply click the Cast button in Chromium to Cast your current tab.*". As I said, I *can* cast what is appearing in the tab. ¶ What I want is to be able to cast the stream *without* its also being displayed in the tab. (What the "Cast to TV" icon on YouTube, Tubi, et al. do.)

Comment: If you consider the example website https://beaufortfrancois.github.io/sandbox/media/remote-playback.html , is this a website where you can do what you want?

Comment: @DanielT. It starts with a small image in my tab, and below it "*Click video cast button or `video.remote.prompt()`*".
Clicking on that that "prompt" button results in; "*Prompt button clicked
Argh! NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'prompt' on 'RemotePlayback': The RemotePlayback API is disabled on this platform.*".
Right click and select "cast" and it correctly casts the tab.
There's no obvious way to cast the image without also playing it in the browser.
¶ This is Ubuntu 20.4.